# Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT I9300) does not restart. It does not go into download mode as well. Please Help

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

My Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT I9300) does not restart. It does not go into download mode as well. Please Help.
Today morning I was checking the weather wizard of my samsung galaxy S3 home screen. Then suddenly the screen got horizontal white, black and pink stripes. I tried back button, home screen button but it kept flashing. Then I even started power off button. Nothing happened for 10-12 seconds. Then suddenly it turned off and at the same time I removed the battery. When I tried to restart it does not boot. I can see the blue LED indicator flashing when I switch on but the screen remains black. It even shows red LED when I tried to charge it. I tried removing battery and replacing, removing sim and even holding start button, home and volume down button to get into download mode. But nothing happens. I can connect to laptop but the folder shows no content. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Broken screen
2. Hard bricked

To find out what you can try doing the fastboot combination for a couple of seconds and then connecting it to your computer and see if it shows up in `fastboot devices`command (with correct drivers installed.